# Exact match search on text field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch to search data. My data contains text field and when I tried to match query on input, it outputs the input with another string.

**_mapping**

```
"direction": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 256
    }
  }
}
```

**Elastic Data**

```
[
  {
   direction: "North"
  },
  {
   direction: "North East"
  }
]
```

**Query**

```
{
  match: {
    "direction" : {
      query: "North",
      operator : "and"
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
   direction: "North"
  },
  {
   direction: "North East"
  }
]
```

**Expected Result**

```
[
  {
   direction: "North"
  }
]
```

> Noted: It should output exact match direction

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at [`Term Queries`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) which are used on [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) datatype to perform exact match searches.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "direction.keyword": {
                "value": "North"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason you observe what you observe, is because you are querying on [`Text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) field using [`Match Query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html). The values of the text field are broken down into tokens which are then stored in inverted indexes. This process is called [`Analysis`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html). **Text fields are not meant to be used for exact match.**

Also note that whatever words/tokens you'd mention in [`Match Query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), they would also go through the analysis phase before getting executed.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Based on you mapping, you should not search on field `direction` but on `direction.keyword` if you want exact match. The field `direction` is type `text` and gets analyzed - in your case to the words `north` and `east`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
{ "query" : { "bool" : { "must": { "term": { "direction": "North" } } } } }